# Flutter Error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using a long list in Flutter. All the items are rendering fine but I also receive the following error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3
```

The following is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: getList(),
 );
}
```

The following is my `getList()` method:

```
Widget getList (){
List<String> list = getListItems();
ListView myList = new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
  return new ListTile(
    title: new Text(list[index]),
  );
});
return myList;
}
```

And the following is my `getListItem()` method:

```
List<String> getListItems(){
return ["Faizan", "Usman", "Naouman"];
}
```

the following is the screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: add `itemCount` parameter to `ListView.builder()` constructor

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You should pass the `itemCount` parameter to the `ListView.builder` to allow it to know the item count

```
Widget getList() {
  List<String> list = getListItems();
  ListView myList = new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(list[index]),
    );
  });
  return myList;
}
```

Comment: What if my list doesn't have a fixed length (e.g. In infinite scrolling)?

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa Listview.builder is for a list with a specified length, you can use listview if you don`t know the length

Comment: @ElhamKeshavarz with itemCount:list.length you get infinite scrolling to the last item

Comment: it doesn't help in case with AnimatedList, unfortunately

Comment: I am using SliverList, where i dont find any option for specifying itemCount :(

Comment: @ElhamKeshavarz your comment is wrong and misleading. This is the official description of the `listview.builder`:

`This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

Providing a non-null itemCount improves the ability of the ListView to estimate the maximum scroll extent.`

Comment: I saw it here: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTwTKwK3hGc` towards the last few seconds of the bit.

Comment: If we _don't_ provide an `itemCount` (as the OP did), how many times will `listview.builder` be called? forever?

Comment: @Konstantin
In AnimatedList case, you should clear list items at first and then add new items

Comment: having same error but already added itemcount in the builder

Answer (score 18):

This error occurs when you run out of values when iterating over an array. In the case of the `ListView` component missing the itemCount prop, the component attempts to continue to iterate but is unaware when to complete so it eventually continues on out of range (the length of the array).

You could also see this error after running a poorly set up `for loop`. For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    print(arr[i]);
}
```

This dart code would result in a range error as well. The array has 3 items yet we attempt to iterate 4 times.

Answer (score 5):

if you use `substring` and if did not make condition properly then you will get an error

Comment: its range issue, not related to `substring`

Comment: final showd = note.description.length > 60
        ? note.description.substring(0, 50)
        : note.description; here you will get range error also

Comment: I was using substring(0, 3) on a value that has only 1 character..placing a check of string.length solved the problem...mentioning the substring attribute led me to the culprit...thnx

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my `itemCount:list.lenght` parameter was fine but somewhere in my listTile,
I used wrong parameter for `list.indexWhere()` function .When I fix function, error was gone.

Comment: Yes, you get the error in the outer list, but it may also have to do with a range error in another list called in the tile. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `StreamBuilder` then you must use this line of code:

```
  StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Tooth")
                  .orderBy("date", descending: false).snapshots() ,
                
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                 
                    if(snapshot.hasData)
                    {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only( top: 20.0),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                           DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
 },
                      );
                    }
                   
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The Listview.Builder contains itemcount attribute. You could try this:

```
Listview.Builder(
    itemCount : list.length,
    itemBuilde:(context, index)=>
);
```

Comment: Than you for providing an answer. Unfortunately, your answer is just a duplicate of the accepted answer. In the future, please try to provide context with your answers, or explanations as to why the answer you are providing correctly solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the item count.

```
itemCount: item.length///item is your list name
```

hope answer the Question

Answer (score 0):

This mainly occurs when you are using wrong index value to fetch data from list. in my case, I was doing the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This type Error Call indexoutofboundsexception in java but in dart case you get error like this 
 **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: 13..........................#0** 
but you have write    `int lastElement = myList[myList.length];` instant of this ** 
 `int lastElement = myList[myList.length - 1];`**
for example

```
  List<int> myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
int lastElement = myList[myList.length - 1]; // Accessing the 12th element
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case also this error was due to substring on null value i just removed or used ?? and it solved "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3" error.

Answer (score -2):

```
Widget getListView(){
  var itemList = getListElement();
   var list = ListView.builder(
     itemCount: itemList.length,
       itemBuilder:(context, index){
         return ListTile(
           title: Text(itemList[index]),   
         );
         }
   );
   return list;
}
```