# Flutter listView builder keeps giving this error: "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..19, inclusive: 20"

Tags: listview, flutter

I have this news ApI, which gets latest news updates but my listview gives me an error even when i have an item "itemCount" to its length.

i tried "_total.length" on the Itemcount but it gives me an error.. which says "The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'int'.

Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'".

```
class _NewsUpdateState extends State<NewsUpdate> {

  List _bottomItems = 
   [
    {"icon": FontAwesomeIcons.fire, "index": 0},
    {"icon": FontAwesomeIcons.moneyBillAlt, "index": 1},
    {"icon": FontAwesomeIcons.bell, "index": 2},
    {"icon": FontAwesomeIcons.futbol, "index": 3},
  ];

  String _apiKey = '46d80623786da4a97847da2b6cd7747';

  int _currentTab = 0;
  String _apiUrl = '';
  int _total = 0;
  List _articles = [];
  bool _loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    changeTab(index: 0);
  }

  void changeTab({int index = 0}) {
    //tab1 is about top-headlines
    //tab2 is about bitcoins
    //tab3 = apple
    //tab4 = techcrunch

    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        _apiUrl =
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=za&apiKey=' +
                _apiKey;
        break;
      case 1:
        _apiUrl =
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=za&category=business&apiKey=' +
                _apiKey;
        break;
      case 2:
        _apiUrl =
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=za&category=entertainment&apiKey=' +
                _apiKey;
        break;
      case 3:
        _apiUrl =
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=za&category=sports&apiKey=' +
                _apiKey;
        break;
    }

    print(_apiUrl);

    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
      _total = 0;
      _articles = [];
    });

    http.get(_apiUrl).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _total = data['totalResults'];
        _articles = data['articles'];
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Latest News",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        elevation: 5.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigation(context),
      body: new SafeArea(child: _buildBody(context)),
    );
  }

  _buildBottomNavigation(BuildContext context) {
    var _items = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[];

    for (var item in _bottomItems) {
      _items.add(new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(
          item['icon'],
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: new Text(''),
      ));
    }

    return new BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: _bottomItems.map((x) {
          return new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(
              x['icon'],
              color: _currentTab == x['index'] ? Colors.black : Colors.black38,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _currentTab = x['index'];
              });
              changeTab(index: x['index']);
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    if (_loading) {
      return new SpinKitCircle(
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 50.0,
      );
    }

    print(_articles);

    return new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
          child: new ListItem(data: _articles[index]),
        );
      },
      itemCount: _total,
    );
  }
}
```

This should set the actual length of the total result from the api to the itemcount

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967624/flutter-error-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-not-in-range-0-2-inclusive)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue:

you have to also pass the `itemCount` parameter

```
child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(list[index].description);
    }),
```

Comment: itemCount:list.length fixed this error for me , thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I have similar error, but i have used Listview and not Listview.builder, can you tell how do I fix it?

Comment: @luckyhandler any idea why the `itemCount` is not set as a required parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The number 'totalResults' is bigger then the number of articles actually got in the request, therefor your `setState` should look like this:

```
setState(() {
        _total = data['articles'].length;
        _articles = data['articles'];
        _loading = false;
      });
```

You can use the `page` and `pageSize` parameters to get more articles from the api. Take a look at their documentaion on https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines.

Comment: how will i implement the pagesize and page parameter? because having trouble doing so.. first time using APIs

Comment: you can do `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=za&category=business&pageSize=100&apiKey=...` and it well get the first 100 (instead of the first 20) or  `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=za&category=business&pageSize=30&page=2&apiKey=...` and it well get the articles 30-60.