# Flutter Error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3 in Swiper

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am using Swiper in flutter the error is occurring when I add 4 element in the list.

I referred to the link [Flutter Error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967624/flutter-error-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-not-in-range-0-2-inclusive) but unable to implement the same in Swiper.

```
class _LipsOutlineState extends State<LipsOutline> {
  var nimage = ["img/1.png",
                "img/2.png",
                "img/3.png",
                "img/4.png", <-- When I add this element

  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return new Image.asset(nimage[index],);
        },
        itemCount: nimage.length,
        itemWidth: 200,
        itemHeight: 100,
        control: new SwiperControl(),
        layout: SwiperLayout.CUSTOM,
        customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(startIndex: 0,stateCount: nimage.length) <-- Tried Changing here didnt work
            .addRotate([0/180, 0.0, 0/180])
            .addTranslate([
          Offset(0.0, 0.0),
          Offset(0.0, 0.0),
          Offset(0.0, 0.0),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try starting at index 0,why are you starting at -1?

Comment: customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(startIndex: 0,stateCount: nimage.length) <-- tried this same result

Answer (score 0):

User `stateCount` as 3.

```
customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(startIndex: 0,stateCount: 3)
```

I dont know the reason behind it but it worked.
I would be glad if anyone can explain the reason behind this mysterious 3