# Error: RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 10 - creating a userstable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a panel in which I can see all user data which are stored in my firebase.
For this task I decided to use the responsive_table:^0.2.0+2 code. (https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_table) This is a table with hard coded data.

For a better overview I decided to divide the code in the page-layout file and a methods/variables file.

DataPage is my overview page in which I have my page layout and TestTable is the page for the methods and variables.
Before I used my firebase to connect my data to the table, I tried to use hard coded data which actually worked. But after I have implemented the connection to my firebase I get the error (when I am running the code):

```
Error: RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 10
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:5646:11)
at RangeError.checkValidRange (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:136032:21)
at [dartx.getRange] (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:18141:25)
at test_table.TestTable.init.mockPullData (http://localhost:51303/packages/bestfitnesstrackereu/pages/user_administration/test_table.dart.lib.js:227:63)
at mockPullData.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:43211:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:42983:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:37734:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:38329:49)
at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:38367:17)
at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:38196:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:38232:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:43360:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:43366:13)
at http://localhost:51303/dart_sdk.js:38600:9
```

Also I get a permanent loading symbole (the blue bar below the headers):
[image]

I can't find the reason, why I am getting this error. I hope you can help me.

**Edit:**

I just found out, that the page is working. When I click on "Rows per page" and select any number (10,20,50,100), then the page refresh and shows the users in my firebase. It is just an initialize problem.

Now I just need to find out where the problem is and fix it.

**Edit 2:**

I changed initializeData() methode from:

```
usersTableSource = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, currentPerPage).toList();
```

to:

```
usersTableSource = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _users.length).toList();
```

Now the initialisation won't need the minimum amount of currentPerPage as content.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

**DataPage.dart code:**

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:responsive_table/responsive_table.dart';
import 'package:bestfitnesstrackereu/pages/user_administration/test_table.dart';

class DataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DataPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DataPageState createState() => _DataPageState();
}

class _DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TestTable testTable = Provider.of<TestTable>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("RESPONSIVE DATA TABLE"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text("home"),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.storage),
              title: Text("data"),
              onTap: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: 700,
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 1,
                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                    child: ResponsiveDatatable(
                      title: TextButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () => {},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        label: Text("new item"),
                      ),
                      reponseScreenSizes: [ScreenSize.xs],
                      actions: [
                        if (testTable.isSearch)
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Enter search term based on ' +
                                        testTable.searchKey
                                            .replaceAll(new RegExp('[\\W_]+'), ' ')
                                            .toUpperCase(),
                                    prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            testTable.isSearch = false;
                                          });
                                          testTable.initializeData();
                                        }),
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {})),
                                onSubmitted: (value) {
                                  testTable.filterData(value);
                                },
                              )),
                        if (!testTable.isSearch)
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  testTable.isSearch = true;
                                });
                              })
                      ],
                      headers: testTable.headers,
                      source: testTable.usersTableSource,
                      selecteds: testTable.selecteds,
                      showSelect: testTable.showSelect,
                      autoHeight: false,
                      dropContainer: (data) {
                        if (int.tryParse(data['id'].toString()).isEven) {
                          return Text("is Even");
                        }
                        return _DropDownContainer(data: data);
                      },
                      onChangedRow: (value, header) {
                        /// print(value);
                        /// print(header);
                      },
                      onSubmittedRow: (value, header) {
                        /// print(value);
                        /// print(header);
                      },
                      onTabRow: (data) {
                        print(data);
                      },
                      onSort: testTable.onSort,
                      expanded: testTable.expanded,
                      sortAscending: testTable.sortAscending,
                      sortColumn: testTable.sortColumn,
                      isLoading: testTable.isLoading,
                      onSelect: testTable.onSelected,
                      onSelectAll: testTable.onSelectAll,
                      footers: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          child: Text("Rows per page:"),
                        ),
                        if (testTable.perPages.isNotEmpty)
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            child: DropdownButton<int>(
                              value: testTable.currentPerPage,
                              items: testTable.perPages
                                  .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                                child: Text("$e"),
                                value: e,
                              ))
                                  .toList(),
                              onChanged: testTable.onChanged,
                              isExpanded: false,
                            ),
                          ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          child:
                          Text("$testTable.currentPage - $testTable.currentPerPage of $testTable.total"),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                            size: 16,
                          ),
                          onPressed: testTable.previous,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 16),
                          onPressed: testTable.next,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ])),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: testTable.initializeData,
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh_sharp),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DropDownContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;
  const _DropDownContainer({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _children = data.entries.map<Widget>((entry) {
      Widget w = Row(
        children: [
          Text(entry.key.toString()),
          Spacer(),
          Text(entry.value.toString()),
        ],
      );
      return w;
    }).toList();

    return Container(
      /// height: 100,
      child: Column(
        /// children: [
        ///   Expanded(
        ///       child: Container(
        ///     color: Colors.red,
        ///     height: 50,
        ///   )),

        /// ],
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**TestTable.dart code:**

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_table/responsive_table.dart';

import '../../datamodels/user_model.dart';
import '../../services/user_services.dart';

class TestTable with ChangeNotifier {

  List<int> perPages = [10, 20, 50, 100];
  int total = 100;
  int currentPerPage = 10;
  List<bool> expanded;
  String searchKey = "id";

  int currentPage = 1;
  bool isSearch = false;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sourceOriginal = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sourceFiltered = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> usersTableSource = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> selecteds = [];
  // ignore: unused_field
  String selectableKey = "id";

  String sortColumn;
  bool sortAscending = true;
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool showSelect = true;
  var random = new Random();

   List<DatatableHeader> headers = [
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "UID",
         value: "uid",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "Benutzername",
         value: "username",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "E-Mail",
         value: "email",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "Vorname",
         value: "first name",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "Nachname",
         value: "last name",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "Geburtsdatum",
         value: "birthday",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
     DatatableHeader(
         text: "Geschlecht",
         value: "gender",
         show: true,
         sortable: true,
         textAlign: TextAlign.left),
  ];

  UserServices _userServices = UserServices();
  List<UserModel> _users = <UserModel>[];
  List<UserModel> get users => _users;

  Future _loadFromFirebase() async {
    _users = await _userServices.getAllUsers();
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _getUsersData() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> temps = [];
    var i = _users.length;
    print(i);
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    for (UserModel userData in _users) {
      temps.add({
        "uid": userData.uid,
        "username": userData.username ,
        "email": userData.email ,
        "first name": userData.firstName ,
        "last name": userData.lastName ,
        "birthday": userData.birthday ,
        "gender": userData.gender ,
      });
      i++;
    }
    return temps;
  }

   initializeData() async {
     mockPullData();
   }

   mockPullData() async {
     expanded = List.generate(currentPerPage, (index) => false);

     isLoading = true;
     notifyListeners();
     await _loadFromFirebase();
     sourceOriginal.clear();
     sourceOriginal.addAll(_getUsersData());
     sourceFiltered = sourceOriginal;
     total = sourceFiltered.length;
     usersTableSource = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, currentPerPage).toList();
     isLoading = false;
     notifyListeners();
   }

   resetData({start: 0}) async {
     isLoading = true;
     notifyListeners();
     var _expandedLen =
     total - start < currentPerPage ? total - start : currentPerPage;
     expanded = List.generate(_expandedLen as int, (index) => false);
     usersTableSource.clear();
     usersTableSource = sourceFiltered.getRange(start, start + _expandedLen).toList();
     isLoading = false;
     notifyListeners();
     //hier future weggemacht
   }

   filterData(value) {
     isLoading = true;
     notifyListeners();

     try {
       if (value == "" || value == null) {
         sourceFiltered = sourceOriginal;
       } else {
         sourceFiltered = sourceOriginal
             .where((data) => data[searchKey]
             .toString()
             .toLowerCase()
             .contains(value.toString().toLowerCase()))
             .toList();
       }

       total = sourceFiltered.length;
       var _rangeTop = total < currentPerPage ? total : currentPerPage;
       expanded = List.generate(_rangeTop, (index) => false);
       usersTableSource = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
     } catch (e) {
       print(e);
     }

     isLoading = false;
     notifyListeners();
   }

   onSort(dynamic value){
     isLoading = true;
     notifyListeners();
     sortColumn = value;
     sortAscending = !sortAscending;
     if (sortAscending) {
       sourceFiltered.sort((a, b) =>
           b["$sortColumn"].compareTo(a["$sortColumn"]));
     } else {
       sourceFiltered.sort((a, b) =>
           a["$sortColumn"].compareTo(b["$sortColumn"]));
     }
     var _rangeTop = currentPerPage < sourceFiltered.length
         ? currentPerPage
         : sourceFiltered.length;
     usersTableSource = sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
     searchKey = value;

     isLoading = false;
     notifyListeners();
   }

   onSelected(bool value, Map <String, dynamic> item){
     print("$value  $item ");
     if (value) {
       selecteds.add(item);
     } else {
       selecteds.removeAt(selecteds.indexOf(item));
     }
     notifyListeners();
   }

   onSelectAll(bool value){
     if (value) {
       selecteds = usersTableSource.map((entry) => entry).toList().cast();
     } else {
       selecteds.clear();
     }
     notifyListeners();
   }

   onChanged(int value){
       currentPerPage = value;
       currentPage = 1;
       resetData();
       notifyListeners();
   }

   previous(){
     currentPage == 1
         ? null
         : () {
     var nextSet = currentPage - currentPerPage;
     currentPage = nextSet > 1 ? nextSet : 1;
     resetData(start: currentPage - 1);
   };
     notifyListeners();
  }

  next(){
    currentPage + currentPerPage - 1 > total
        ? null
        : () {
      var nextSet = currentPage + currentPerPage;

      currentPage = nextSet < total
          ? nextSet
          : total - currentPerPage;
      resetData(start: nextSet - 1);
    };
    notifyListeners();
  }

  TestTable.init() {
    initializeData();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's related to [loop range try to pass range as per data length see this post you will find you answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967624/flutter-error-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-not-in-range-0-2-inclusive)

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    print(arr[i]);
}
```

check out boundary of data length

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. I am using normal List and not ListView - how should I set the List length? Also I have defined the length of the list. As example: methode _getUsersData() -> var i = _users.length; and then counting it up until all users are displayed.

Comment: could you please share on which line you find this error. try to edit question upload on which line it shows error.